# Selenium Firefox webdriver results in error: connection refused

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, connection-refused

Same setup was working in another Linux server. I just migrated to AWS (Centos 7) and am now facing this problem.

- Mozilla Firefox 52.6.0
- Selenium 3.8.1
- Python 2.7

**My code:**

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.set_window_size(1366, 768)
browser.get('http://www.vionblog.com/')
browser.set_script_timeout(30)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(30) # seconds
browser.save_screenshot('vionblog.png')

browser.quit()
display.stop()
```

**Error:**

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
>     browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 158, in __init__
>     keep_alive=True)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
>     self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
>     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You need to download the *GeckoDriver* binary from this [site](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), place it anywhere within your system and explicitly mention the location of the *GeckoDriver* binary as per the following line of code to initiate the *Web Browser Client* :

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
```